# Can a multiperfect number be a perfect power?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers, perfect-powers

(Note:  The following post is an offshoot of this earlier MSE question: [Can a multiperfect number be a perfect square?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1936200).)

Let $\sigma(x)$ denote the classical *sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$.

A number $m$ satisfying
$$\sigma(m)=2m$$
is said to be *perfect*.

More generally, we call any number $n$ satisfying
$$\sigma(n)=kn$$
for $k \in \mathbb{N}$ to be *multiperfect* (or $k$-*perfect*).

[It is known that multiperfect numbers cannot be squares.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1936200)

[Furthermore, it is also known that perfect numbers cannot be perfect powers.](http://upforthecount.com/math/perfect.html)

I found a reference to the last statement in Walter Nissen's [Concise, remarkable facts about perfect numbers](http://upforthecount.com/math/perfect.html):

```
---

Perfect Naturals
are not
Perfect Powers ( e.g. , perfect squares , perfect cubes , etc. )

---
```

Here is my question:

> Can a multiperfect number be a perfect power?

**Update (August 9, 2020 - 12:04 PM Manila time)** I have posted a closely related question in MO [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/368675).

Comment: Just to mention it : $1$ is not considered to be a multi-perfect number. Currently, I am checking the cubes upto some limit, no idea yet for a proof.

Comment: No cube upto $10^{21}$ is multi-perfect. No $5$ th power upto $10^{30}$ is multi-perfect.

Comment: I checked all the multi-perfect numbers in the b-file of [A007691](http://oeis.org/A007691), and none of them were perfect powers. This is all the way up to $n \approx 1.8 \cdot 10^{303}$

Comment: @VarunVejalla:  Please post your last comment as an answer, so that I can upvote it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked all the multiperfect numbers from [this site](http://wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de/achim/mpn.html), which include all the multiperfect numbers in the b-file of [A007691](http://oeis.org/A007691), as well as additional ones. The largest number that was in the list was $\approx 10^{34850339}$. None of those values were perfect powers.

What I did find for all multiperfect numbers is that there was at least one prime factor with an exponent of exactly $1$ in the prime factorization. If this could be proved for all multiperfect numbers, then the conjecture that there is no number that is both multiperfect and a perfect power could be proven.

Comment: Just curious, @VarunVejalla, what software did you use to check this?

Comment: I just used plain old Python. The numbers from Flammenkamp's site were easy to check since they were prime factorized.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot!  =)