# How do number shapes relate to k-perfect numbers?

Tags: prime-numbers, perfect-numbers

We know that all perfect numbers are a Mersenne prime, multiplied with the corresponding power of 2 for that prime, and then halved.$$2^{n}-1(2^{n-1})$$ It is also true that all perfect numbers are triangular numbers.

I'm trying to find other patterns. We know that tri-perfect numbers exist. The sum of tri-perfect number's factors equals 3 times the tri-perfect number.

I was trying to think what patterns there are? 120, a tri-perfect number is hexagonal, but 672 is not. Is there some easy formula to find the shape of a k-perfect number? (where k is 2 for perfect, 3 for tri-perfect etc). Does the number of dimensions needed to display k-perfect numbers increase as k does?

Also, even perfect numbers are closely related to Mersenne primes. Is there another type of prime number for tri-perfect numbers? Do you have to do something else to a Mersenne prime to get a tri-perfect number?

I find perfect numbers perfectly interesting but man they are confusing. Thanks, Andy

Comment: Not true. We only know that all even perfect numbers are of that form, and that all even perfect numbers are triangular. Nobody has proven the non-existence of an odd perfect number yet, funnily enough.

Comment: @merelymyself is correct.  It is [currently unknown](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/234528) whether *odd perfect numbers* are triangular or not.  So without a proof for the nonexistence of an odd perfect number, **or** a proof that odd perfect numbers are also triangular, you *cannot say* that **all perfect numbers are triangular**.

Comment: @Opti_byte:  I will have more to say about the shape of a $k$-perfect number (also known as **multiperfect numbers**), which is derived from work of Holdener and one of her past undergraduate research mentees.  Let me pull up that information for you real quick.

Answer (score 1):

From the undergraduate research project titled *The Form of Perfect and Multiperfect Numbers* by **Judy Holdener and Kaitlin Rafferty** (Kenyon College, 2009), we have the following:

> **Euler's Characterization of Odd Perfect Numbers**
>
> - If an odd perfect number exists, then it is of the form
>   $$n = p^{\alpha} {q_1}^{2\beta_1} \cdots {q_r}^{2\beta_r}$$
>   where $p$ and the $q_i$'s are distinct primes, and $p = 1 + 4m_1$ and $\alpha = 1 + 4m_2$.

> **Generalization of Euler's Characterization**
>
> - **Theorem:** Let $n$ be a positive integer with unique factorization
>   $$n = 2^r \prod_{i=1}^{k}{p_i}^{\alpha_i}\prod_{j=1}^{l}{q_j}^{\beta_j},$$
>   with $p_i \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $q_j \equiv 3 \pmod 4$.  If at least one $\beta_j$ is odd, then $4 \mid \sigma(n)$.  If all the $\beta_j$'s are even then
>   $$\sigma(n) \equiv \begin{cases}{ \prod_{i=1}^{k}{\Bigg(\alpha_i + 1\Bigg)} \pmod 4 \text{ if } n \text{ is even } \\
>   3\prod_{i=1}^{k}{\Bigg(\alpha_i + 1\Bigg)} \pmod 4 \text{ if } n \text{ is odd.}}
>   \end{cases}$$
> - **Corollary:** If $n \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then
>   $$\sigma(n) \equiv \prod_{i=1}^{k}{\Bigg(\alpha_i + 1\Bigg)} \pmod 4,$$
>   and if $n$ is multiperfect with multiplicity $K$, then
>   $$K \equiv \prod_{i=1}^{k}{\Bigg(\alpha_i + 1\Bigg)} \pmod 4.$$
> - **Theorem:** If $n$ is an odd multiperfect number with multiplicity $K$ and $2 \parallel K$, then $n = p^{\alpha} m^2$ where $p$ is prime and $p \equiv \alpha \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

The paper is available via [JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24345300).

Comment: This [answer to a closely related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3784544/28816) is then relevant.